# Azure Active Directory Connection String

Tags: azure, iis, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I've been trying to set up my IIS website's connection string to connect to an Azure SQL Database with the following connection string:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=tcp:some.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDB;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;" />
```

The IIS application pool is using a service account which has Azure Active Directory privileges and is added as an user on the Azure SQL Database.

This works fine on my local development machine (probably because it is using my credentials and not a service account) but when I place the site on IIS I get:

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for logging in via Azure AD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you been through this troubleshooting guide, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/#5-configure-your-client-computers?

In particular, do you have .NET Framework 4.6 or later installed?