# ADO.Net (Azure AD) error "keyword not supported : authentication "

Tags: c#-4.0, ado.net

I am trying to connect to Azure db with Azure AD credentials through c# code (Code is below). It works fine on my system. But when I deploy it to a 32 bit VM, it shows error

> "Keyword not supported : authentication".

The VM has .Net framework 4.5 installed (But not Visual Studio). Application is targeting .Net Framework 4.5.

As per my observations, system.data for framework 2.0 does not support authentication keyword for SQLConnection class. But my application is targetting 4.5 , so it should work fine with 4.5 installed. can anyone help to resolve it. Below is my code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string ConnectionString =
      @"Data Source=mydatabase.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Password; UID=user.name@microsoft.contoso.com; PWD=Test@pswd";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("connected");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Active Directory Connection String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943369/azure-active-directory-connection-string)

Comment: This links suggests .Net Framework 4.6. Installed it and the error is gone, however it needs adalsql.dll. It looks for the dll in system32 directory. After installing Active Directory for Sql Server msi from microsoft it worked. But my problem now is, i want to make it work without having my customers to install azure active directory msi.

Comment: I tried adding reference and making it copy to local in a hope that it will remove the dependency, but it did not help. I want to embed this dll into my installer so that end user would not have to install msi explicitly

Comment: @VineetKumar - Did you resolve this issue as I am now having same issue

Comment: I am facing this exact same issue

Answer (score 3):

This answer is regarding dotnet core and not .NET Framework 4.5/6, so it does not directly answer your question. However, it may help you with respect to deployment of code to your customers.

I encountered the same error attempting to connect from dotnet-core. [From Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-2#data):

> Starting with .NET Core 2.2, an access token issued by Azure Active Directory can be used to authenticate to an Azure SQL database. To support access tokens, the [`AccessToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.accesstoken#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_AccessToken) property has been added to the [`SqlConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection) class. To take advantage of AAD authentication, download version 4.6 of the `System.Data.SqlClient` NuGet package. In order to use the feature, you can obtain the access token value using the [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) for .NET contained in the [`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) NuGet package.

Comment: These instructions (given by Microsoft) are very unclear, I've tried doing this using these instructions >> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#modify-aspnet-core, yet when I specify a user ID I get `Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Connection refused` and when I don't specify a user I (predictably) get `Login failed for user ''`.